# VB.NET textbox to listbox new line

Tags: vb.net, asterisk

I have a list of 4 digit extensions that I'm pulling out of my server

```
cmd = sshClient.RunCommand("asterisk -x 'sip show peers' | grep -w OK | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F'/' '{print $1}'")
TextBox1.Text = cmd.Result
```

TextBox1 does fill up with the extension list, but it is all in 1 line

(btw, if I change it from TextBox1 to Label1, then I get them in separate lines)

Then, with button2 (to get the list into a ListBox) I have

```
Dim ext As String
ext = TextBox1.Text
ListBox1.Items.Add(ext)
```

But I get the list in 1 item and no spaces (it doesn't mater if it is from the TextBox or Label)

I tried adding

```
If TextBox1.Text.Length > 4 Then TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Insert(4, Environment.NewLine)
```

But it adds a new line for the first 4 digits (1 extension) only, the rest are in 1 line

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: You would have to split on the character that separates your extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string data returned by asterisk is probably separated by line feeds (ASCII value of 10).  Split the return string on `Chr(10)` and use the `.AddRange(ext)` function to add all of the items to the listbox:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(ext.Split(New Char() {Chr(10)}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer will vary a bit depending on whether you are using WinForms, WPF, etc - I am assuming WinForms.

Check that your textbox is set to `Multiline = true` - if not, that may fix your first problem.  But more fundamentally, @LarsTech is on the right track.  Assign `cmd.Result` to a new string variable (instead of directly to `TextBox1.Text`) then split it into a string array with `String.Split()`, then loop through the array adding each one separately to your ListBox individually. You won't be able to get multiple items into a Listbox with a single Items.Add statement regardless of how you handle your line breaks.

If that is all that your loop is doing, then you can use `ListBox.AddRange()` to add the whole array at once.